# Creating a .TXT file with new lines within the file

Tags: python, file, newline

I am having issues when writing the file that within the txt file it does not place the second message to the next line. (When it prints to the screen it work as I intend it to work, but not in the file itself)

Note: My python version is 2.7.3

```
import os.path

home = os.path.expanduser("~")
check1 = os.path.exists(home + '/test.txt')

if check1 == False:
f = open(home + '/test.txt', 'a')
f.write("First line\n")
f.write("Second line")
f.close()

elif check1 == True:   
with open(home + '/test.txt') as f:
for line in f:
print line
f.close()
```

this is the basis for my code.

Thank you,
Stuart

Comment: How are you viewing the file?

Comment: @jpmc26: Yes I have opened the file and that is exactly why I asked the question

Comment: I asked *how* you viewed the file. What software did you use? I'm guessing Notepad, and if I'm right, that would explain a great many things.

Comment: It looks like there are some errors in your indentation, it's more likely that more people will take a look at your provided test code if the indentation is correct.

Comment: @jpmc26: it is a txt so I viewed it in notepad

Comment: jpmc26 asked _how_ you are opening the file. Depending on what method you are using to view the file contents, you may see certain parts of text appear in different ways (notably line breaks).

Comment: @orange1: the indentation issue is due to the format it asked of me to do when i posted this, as I stated, this works when it compiles, but it isnt what i wanted to have within the txt file

Comment: @Jordan: What i am saying is I clicked the file itself.

Comment: The file puts both lines on the same line in the txt file, i am asking how to solve that to have it write in the txt file so I can have the "first line" be first and "second line" be on the second line

Answer (score 1):

You used a Unix style line ending and then used a Windows specific text viewer to look at it. Notepad doesn't recognize a `\n` as a newline character; it requires Windows style line endings: `\r\n`.

Go read up about line endings and how different OSes have different defaults. Increase your awareness and your knowledge of this issue. Then do this:

1. Put `import os` at the top.
2. `f.write("First line" + os.linesep)`

Comment: @Stuart You're welcome, but do go and read about it. This is not the last time you're going to have to think about this problem. Also, it is good etiquette on StackOverflow to accept the answer that helps you solve your problem. Please consider doing so.

Comment: @Stuart: If you [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open) the file in [universal-newline](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) mode by appending a `'U` to the mode — i.e. `'aU'` and `'rU'` — Python will handle this issue for you and would convert the `\n' you had as needed.